# asp.net post - specify url for response

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post

We are implementing webAPI through post with another company. Basically, we are sending a web request and then the other company is sending its response back:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(toUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.KeepAlive = true;

// Send Request
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(RequestProcessor.ToQueryString(request));
    sw.Close();
}

// Get Response
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

the problem is that normally all other companies we integrate with, send their response back to where the response originated from so the code above works perfectly. This time, this particular vendor wants us to specify postback url. So when we get the result it look like this:

```
<html><head><script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>window.location ="specify postback url here";</script></head><body></body></html>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

the code is located in a separate project (bin) and called by the page that needs it. Furthermore there may be hundreds of different pages. So basically, what would be the url to specify in "specify postback url here" to make sure that their response actually goes to where our request came from?

Comment: So, let me see if I got this staight. Your company recieves requests from other companies, so your company requests to the vendor and then you return the value to the company who requested it?

Comment: Yes, for example, 1.) we send a request using POSTt to www.makeacall.com/processcall.aspx (our parameters would include a number to call and a message to say) 2.) the other company would send a response to us with the results